# custom posts permalinks url rewriting

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

My permalinks are: /%postname%

I currently use Custom Post Permalinks to rewrite my permalinks. It work well, but... I dlike to have some url like: **www.mysite.com/permalinks_of_my_custom_posts.php** >> **www.mysite.com/mario-games.php**

If I use the plugin to do that I have to write */%list-mario%.php* and it's ok,slug is rewrite... Well ... not so much because if I write another custom posts and do the same way, for exemple : */%list-firemen-games.php*, it's ok, I have my **www.mysite.com/firemen-games.php** BUT, **www.mysite.com/mario-games.php** has became unaccessible.

But, (many butt there sorry :D) If I write something before the slug, for example: */test/%list-mario%.php* , my url is ok and it work ... So I have **www.mysite.com/test/mario-games.php** and **www.mysite.com/firemen-games.php** and I want **www.mysite.com/mario-games.php** and **www.mysite.com/firemen-games.php** and other ...

It s like when I want multiple url like **www.mysite.com/mario-games.php**   a var is erased by another and only the last work.

An other solution would be to have some page.php ...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason adding second permalinks like that makes the first type inaccessible is because WordPress is interpretting both `list-firemen-games` and `list-mario` as `list-firemen-games` post types. To WordPress, the regular expression that is registered looks exactly the same (both look something like `([^/]+)\.php/?`), so when it pulls that regular expression, it's going to match that pattern against the first entry it finds in the rewrite rules; in this case, `list-firemen-games`.
The reason it was working when you added `test` to the permalink is because now the regex for `list-mario` looks like `test/([^/]+)\.php/?`.

If you want both types to have the same permastruct, but want to differentiate firemen from mario, I suggest using a custom taxonomy for the post type.

Comment: Nice ! I understand how it work now, Thank you very much :)